# Display specific dates within a date range

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB form with 2 datetimepicker componenets (d1, d2), 7 checkboxes for the days of the week and one datagridview

I need to be able to specify a date range (ie from 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-31) and select the days of the week (ie Monday and Wednesday based on the  checkboxes) and the datagridview will be filled with all the Mondays and Wednesdays of that date range.

Please, I really appreciate the help since I am not that strong with date functionalities in VB.NET.

Thank you very much,
ITJunior

Comment: Please read [ask]. Stack overflow isn't a tutorial site - It's for people who have a problem with their code and have research it and are still unable to find an answer

Answer (score 0):

That might look something like...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim startDate As Date = d1.Value.Date ' removes any time values
    Dim stopDate As Date = d2.Value.Date ' removes any time values
    If stopDate >= startDate Then
        Dim DayChecked As Boolean
        While startDate <= stopDate
            Select Case startDate.DayOfWeek
                Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
                    DayChecked = cbSunday.Checked

                Case DayOfWeek.Monday
                    DayChecked = cbMonday.Checked

                Case DayOfWeek.Tuesday
                    DayChecked = cbTuesday.Checked

                Case DayOfWeek.Wednesday
                    DayChecked = cbWednesday.Checked

                Case DayOfWeek.Thursday
                    DayChecked = cbThursday.Checked

                Case DayOfWeek.Friday
                    DayChecked = cbFriday.Checked

                Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
                    DayChecked = cbSaturday.Checked

            End Select
            If DayChecked Then
                ' ... add startDate to your DataGridView ...
                Debug.Print(startDate.ToString)
            End If

            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Idle_Mind, 
Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed to do. Much appreciated.